# how to use two foreach and the inner foreach loops with a certain ID - laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

ok, I'm really sorry that the title might sound hard to understand.  Really don't know how to shorten up the words.

Anyways, I had some help yesterday and printed what I wanted but I went further and got stuck.
let's say I have two categories and each category has a few products under that category.
I have two tables, category and products.

I have category table with

```
id: 1, name: c1
id: 2, name: c2
```

I have product table with

```
id: 1, name: p1, category_id: 1
id: 2, name: p2, category_id: 1
id: 3, name: p3, category_id: 2
id: 4, name: p4, category_id: 2
```

so in this case p1 and p2 is under the category of c1 and p3, p4 is with category c2.

I am trying to print out things like

```
c1
 -p1
 -p2
c2
 -p3
 -p4
```

so each product prints under its category but what I have now is.

```
c1
 -p1
 -p2
c2
 -p1
 -p2
```

for sure I know why I got both p1, p2 falls under both category but I just don't know how to make it does not repeat and prints the product that falls under that category.

### ProfileController.php

```
    if ($user->count())
    {
        $user = $user->first();
        $title = 'User Profile';

        $categories = Category::all();
        $products = Category::find(1)->products;

        return View::make('profile.user', compact('user', 'title', 'categories', 'products'));
    }
```

### user.blade.php

```
<p>
    <h2>Category</h2>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    {{ $category->name . '<br>'}}
        <ul>
                    @foreach($products as $product)
                        <li>{{ $product->name . '<br>' }}</li>
                    @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endforeach
</p>
```

I understand that `$products = Category::find(1)->products;` is what's making it only print the p1 and p2 but I tried `Category::all()->products` and this gives error. how can I make it so `Category::find(x)->products` the x will change after each loop so it'll be something like `find(1)` , `find(2)` and gets the products printed under the right category.

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) mentions it, just use the method `with("products")`.